# getElementById returns "null" in ngFor loop element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

So I am currently developing an application using Ionic-Angular.
I am using Angular *ngFor to create a number of objects to show in a slider like this:

```
<ion-slides #theSlides [options]="sliderConfig"   id="peerSlide" >
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let peer of peers; let i = index">
       <img id="{{'x' + i}}">
       <p>{{peer.firstname}}</p>
       <p>{{peer.lastname}}</p>
       <p>{{peer.status}}</p>
   </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

The ngFor loop works fine but when I'm trying to access the image element inside by getElementById to set the source of the image it returns null.
This is the type script code which pushes the peer object into the peers array:

```
this.peer_profile_ready.subscribe(
  () => {
      var peer = {
      id: 1,
      firstname: this.peerFirstName,
      lastname: this.peerLastName,
      status: this.peerStatus,
      }
  
    this.peers.push(peer);
    var peerImage = < HTMLImageElement > document.getElementById("x0");
    console.log('peerImage', peerImage)})
```

so now the console returns null.
I appreciate it if you could tell me what is wrong here and what is the best way to access an element inside the ngFor loop.
thank you

Comment: What does the html output look like? Are you sure, that you need the ‘ around the x in the ngfor?

Comment: hi! so at first I didn't use the index property to set the id for element and just used a random id and it didn't work. as i was looking for answers i found that using a index is a way to access the element inside ngFor so i used it and it doesn't work either. the out put shows the firstname and lastname and also the image element is generated with the same id but returns null with getElementById

Comment: Why don't you just set the image src in the template? Failing that the angular way of accessing the elements is using `ViewChildren` rather than `getElementById`.

Comment: thanks for your reply I will try it, the reason is i need to change the source of the image in different scenarios for each peer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your code :

angular has not had the chance to run its "check modified data and update DOM" processing between the two instructions :

```
    this.peers.push(peer);
    var peerImage = < HTMLImageElement > document.getElementById("x0");
```

so when you ask for element `x0`, it is still absent from the DOM.

You would have to wait for the next `ngAfterViewInit()` event to have your code execute with a DOM which contains your `x0` img node. See [angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for more details.

---

What you probably should do :

if you need to update the fields of your `<img>` node, you should probably have your data layer provide the necessary data, not "inject" an html node in your data layer and update its fields from the javascript code.

For example : if you need to update the `src` of the image, add an `src` field in your data :

- example 1 : add an 'src' field in your 'peer' objects

```
// in your javascript code :
 var peer = {
      id: 1,
      src: '/starting/img.png',
      ...
}

// in your html template :
<img id="{{'x' + i}}" [src]="peer.src">
```

- example 2 : have a function return the value for `src` from `peer` :

```
// in your javascript code :
getPeerImage(peer) {
    if (this.state[peer.id] === "ok") {
        return "ok.png";
    } else {
        return "questionmark.png";
    }
}

// in your template :
<img id="{{'x' + i}}" [src]="getPeerImage(peer)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think executing the portion of typescrit code you shared, inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, is the best way to achieve what you want.